# Matlab Related Faster code example

Tags: matlab

Following code runs very slow input is two matrices size 256x256x3. anyone can please tell me how to improve upon the same

```
[row col byt]=size(img_encryp);
    decryp_value=zeros(row,col,3);
    img_encryp = cast(img_encryp,'int32');
     ca1=cast(ca1,'int32');
    for i=1:row
        for j=1:col
            for z=1:3

                % Encryption
                c=de2bi(img_encryp(i,j,z),16);
                d=de2bi(ca1(i,j,z),16);

                for k=1:incr:8
                    c1=bi2de(c(k:k+incr-1));
                    c2=bi2de(d(k:k+incr-1));
                    result=mod((c1-c2),2.^incr);
                    temp_bin(k:k+incr-1)=de2bi(result,incr);   
                end
                decryp_value(i,j,z)=bi2de(temp_bin);

            end

        end
```

Comment: If this is the same question as your previous one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29997900/matlab-related-faster-code, you should edit that question to include your code rather than open a new one.

Comment: This looks like it could probably be achieved orders of magnitude more efficiently with judicious use of [`bitand` and `bitor`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/bit-wise-operations.html) directly on the integers with suitable bitmasks, but without any _explanation_ of what the code inside the loop is meant to do, it's hard to figure it out, especially without knowing missing details like what the allowable values of `incr` are.

Answer (score 0):

Convert binary vectors to decimal numbers functions (`bi2de` and `de2bi`) takes too much time to run. In my opinion if u use `b2d` and `d2b` functions provided in this [link](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/26447-efficient-convertors-between-binary-and-decimal-numbers) will tremendously increase the performance of your code.